# Ubuntu Server - PHP - Call to undefined function http_post_fields()

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am trying install the `pecl_http` extension in my Ubuntu Server in order to use `http_post_fields()` function.

I have installed it using `sudo pecl install pecl_http` and added to my `php.ini`:

```
extension=raphf.so
extension=propro.so
extension=http.so
```

but the script it still giving me the fatal error. I have also try to create a `pecl_http.ini` file inside `conf.d` but not working.

What I am missing??

Also tried to install `raphf`:

```
configure: error: Please install pecl/raphf and activate extension=raphf.so in your php.ini
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr --with-http-libidn-dir=/usr' failed
root@plus:~# sudo pecl install raphf
pecl/raphf is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.0
```